# Gmail 2FA Rejects Thunderbird 68.5.0 With Error "Google couldn't verify that this account belongs to you"

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I am trying to use Thunderbird 68.5.0 to access Gmail, on which I have enabled two factor authentication.  I am able to access my Gmail account in the browser.

In Google accounts, I have generated an app password.

Following the advice at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201470/gmail-login-failure-on-thunderbird), I have set `general.useragent.compatMode.firefox` to `true`.  `javascript.enabled` is already set to `true`, and cookies are already enabled.

Then in Thunderbird I click on the "hamburger" menu button and from there I do `+ New | Existing Mail Account...`  On the dialog that pops up I enter my name, and the email address of my gmail account.  Following the advice on [this page](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131031/why-does-google-consider-thunderbird-not-secure-enough), I enter here the app password (not the normal password of my Gmail account).  I click Continue.

Thunderbird automatically selects IMAP and detects the gmail servers.  I click Done.

Thunderbird then displays another dialog asking for my Gmail email address, and another asking for my password - here I enter the normal password for my Gmail account.  I then get the following error message:

> Google couldn't verify that this account belongs to you

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I have tried many other permutations on the above, no joy.

Comment: Are you adding this account as an IMAP/SMTP account or as a GMail account?  You should use the IMAP route and manually configure it, and use the app specific password in IMAP/SMTP instead of using Google's authentication mechanism. (if you don't find a solution via the Google Authentication option)

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me.  It automatically selects IMAP, I edited my post to clarify that.  If I click the `Manual Config` button, it displays the hostname, port, SSL and Authentication (OAuth2), but there is no place to enter a password - The only option is to click Done and from there it displays the followup dialogs as described in my original message.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.  I was using Authy for 2FA, the solution was to go in to Authy and set up 2FA for Google Accounts.  After that when I repeated the above steps to access Gmail from Thunderbird, it asked me for the code, which Authy generated, I put that in and it worked.